# How to get 1 or 2 decimal places in Java with float data type

Tags: java, decimal

Im having problems with float data type in getting 1 or 2 decimal places only..

but if you look at the code seems okay to me but the output is different.. I dont want to convert into string yet co'z I need to do something else before the printing them out..

Just for testing purposes I did this literally. There are variables and workarounds just to simplify everything. It suppose to end at 12.8 but it yields 12.8000001 that's why it skips my testing..

```
float oh=11.0f;
    int retval=1;
      while (oh<=12.8)
        {
        //System.out.printf("%-11s",dec_format.format(oh)+'K');
     System.out.println(oh);
        oh=oh + 0.3f;
     }
```

output is:
11.0
11.3
11.6
11.900001
12.200001
12.500001

It should end at 12.8 and why with ....00001??

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.printf("%2.3f", 2.887);`

prints `2.887`

`System.out.printf("%2.2f", 2.887);`

prints `2.89`

`System.out.printf("%2.1f", 2.887);`

prints `2.9`